# Error with Systemd in LFS

Tags: linux, systemd, process, chroot, lfs

LFS version: 11.0-systemd
Host: Ubuntu20.04
Chapter in which the problem occurred: 9.5
Commands executed: `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`
Error log:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1).
Can't operate.Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

I use translation. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are in a chroot, and not booted from that system. What you're trying to do with that command is set the date and time, which can be done later. You can skip that command without problems.